# How can I post exact same post but with a few things changed? (with some sort of Automation)

Tags: posts, automation, post-duplication

I wanna duplicate some of my posts but want to change a few variables. For example, I would just like to make some variable in my posts that will be changed every time I give inputs. These can be links or one word changes in post title or somewhere in post. How can I do it? (see an example below where XXXX and Y are variables)

***Post Title:*** Hello this is a sample Post with **XXXX** - Read now!

***Body of my post:***

Hey this is my post welcome, this is post with **XXXX**. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui mi, facilisis quis consequat id, blandit et enim. Nulla viverra tellus elementum ligula vulputate, vel venenatis nisi facilisis. Vivamus in mi eu ipsum molestie bibendum a sed purus. Read more here **Y(link)**.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this using advanced custom fields to setup a field set with X and Y, then build a custom post template where the non-dynamic text is hard coded and us the_field(field_id) function to run a query and pull through your dynamic fields.

I'm not sure what your technical abilities are but that would be how I would do it.